# Multiple Definition в "неправильных" местах. C++,

Tags: c++, sdl2

компилятор пинается на какое-то множественное обьявление, но то, что как он считает множественно обьявляется не существуют в представленном им коде

Логи:

```
      SDL_Renderer * renderer = get_rnd();
                 ^
C:\c++\programs\life3\main.cpp:18:15: warning: unused variable 'window' [-Wunused-variable]
  SDL_Window * window = get_wnd();
               ^
In file included from C:\c++\programs\life3\Presenter/Observer.h:15:0,
                 from C:\c++\programs\life3\main.cpp:13:
C:/c++/programs/life3/Input/Input.h: In member function 'cords Input::check_input()':
C:/c++/programs/life3/Input/Input.h:39:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
In file included from C:\c++\programs\life3\SDL_stuf\cGraf.h:25:0,
                 from C:\c++\programs\life3\SDL_stuf\customSDL.h:19,
                 from C:\c++\programs\life3\SDL_stuf\customSDL.cpp:1:
C:/c++/programs/life3/pcgGlobal.h:35:18: warning: 'Dark' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
 static SDL_Color Dark = {67, 68, 69};    // dark grey
                  ^
C:/c++/programs/life3/pcgGlobal.h:36:18: warning: 'Dark2' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
 static SDL_Color Dark2 = {34, 34, 34};    // dark grey
                  ^
C:/c++/programs/life3/pcgGlobal.h:37:18: warning: 'Grey' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
 static SDL_Color Grey = {187, 191, 194}; // light grey
                  ^
C:/c++/programs/life3/pcgGlobal.h:38:18: warning: 'Red' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
In file included from C:\c++\programs\life3\main.cpp:12:0:
C:\c++\programs\life3\pcgGlobal.h: At global scope:
C:\c++\programs\life3\pcgGlobal.h:35:18: warning: 'Dark' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
 static SDL_Color Dark = {67, 68, 69};    // dark grey
                  ^
C:\c++\programs\life3\pcgGlobal.h:36:18: warning: 'Dark2' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
 static SDL_Color Dark2 = {34, 34, 34};    // dark grey
                  ^
C:\c++\programs\life3\pcgGlobal.h:37:18: warning: 'Grey' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
 static SDL_Color Grey = {187, 191, 194}; // light grey
                  ^
C:\c++\programs\life3\pcgGlobal.h:38:18: warning: 'Red' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
 static SDL_Color Red = {255, 0, 0};      // red
                  ^
C:\c++\programs\life3\pcgGlobal.h:40:18: warning: 'Blue' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
 static SDL_Color Blue = {0, 0, 255};     // blue
                  ^
C:\c++\programs\life3\pcgGlobal.h:42:18: warning: 'Cool' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
 static SDL_Color Cool = { 0,100,100 }; //cool
                  ^
 static SDL_Color Red = {255, 0, 0};      // red
                  ^
C:/c++/programs/life3/pcgGlobal.h:40:18: warning: 'Blue' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
 static SDL_Color Blue = {0, 0, 255};     // blue
                  ^
C:/c++/programs/life3/pcgGlobal.h:42:18: warning: 'Cool' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
 static SDL_Color Cool = { 0,100,100 }; //cool
                  ^
In file included from C:\c++\programs\life3\SDL_stuf\customSDL.h:20:0,
                 from C:\c++\programs\life3\SDL_stuf\cGraf.h:13,
                 from C:\c++\programs\life3\SDL_stuf\cView.cpp:1:
C:/c++/programs/life3/pcgGlobal.h:35:18: warning: 'Dark' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
 static SDL_Color Dark = {67, 68, 69};    // dark grey
                  ^
C:/c++/programs/life3/pcgGlobal.h:36:18: warning: 'Dark2' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
 static SDL_Color Dark2 = {34, 34, 34};    // dark grey
                  ^
C:/c++/programs/life3/pcgGlobal.h:37:18: warning: 'Grey' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
 static SDL_Color Grey = {187, 191, 194}; // light grey
                  ^
C:/c++/programs/life3/pcgGlobal.h:38:18: warning: 'Red' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
 static SDL_Color Red = {255, 0, 0};      // red
                  ^
C:/c++/programs/life3/pcgGlobal.h:40:18: warning: 'Blue' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
 static SDL_Color Blue = {0, 0, 255};     // blue
                  ^
C:/c++/programs/life3/pcgGlobal.h:42:18: warning: 'Cool' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
 static SDL_Color Cool = { 0,100,100 }; //cool
                  ^
obj\Debug\Model\Creature.o: In function `ZN8Creature9make_moveEi':
C:/c++/programs/life3/Model/Creature.cpp:3: multiple definition of `renderera'
obj\Debug\main.o:C:/c++/programs/life3/Input/Input.h:28: first defined here
obj\Debug\Model\Creature.o: In function `ZN8Creature9make_moveEi':
C:/c++/programs/life3/Model/Creature.cpp:3: multiple definition of `windowa'
obj\Debug\main.o:C:/c++/programs/life3/Input/Input.h:28: first defined here
obj\Debug\Model\Turn_Handler.o: In function `ZN6ObjectC2Ev':
C:/c++/programs/life3/Model/Turn_Handler.cpp:5: multiple definition of `renderera'
obj\Debug\main.o:C:/c++/programs/life3/Input/Input.h:28: first defined here
obj\Debug\Model\Turn_Handler.o: In function `ZN6ObjectC2Ev':
C:/c++/programs/life3/Model/Turn_Handler.cpp:5: multiple definition of `windowa'
obj\Debug\main.o:C:/c++/programs/life3/Input/Input.h:28: first defined here
obj\Debug\Model\World.o: In function `ZNSt12_Destroy_auxILb1EE9__destroyIP4FoodEEvT_S4_':
C:/c++/programs/life3/Model/World.cpp:4: multiple definition of `renderera'
obj\Debug\main.o:C:/c++/programs/life3/Input/Input.h:28: first defined here
obj\Debug\Model\World.o: In function `ZNSt12_Destroy_auxILb1EE9__destroyIP4FoodEEvT_S4_':
C:/c++/programs/life3/Model/World.cpp:4: multiple definition of `windowa'
obj\Debug\main.o:C:/c++/programs/life3/Input/Input.h:28: first defined here
obj\Debug\SDL_stuf\customSDL.o: In function `ZSt4moveIRNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEEONSt16remove_referenceIT_E4typeEOS8_':
C:/c++/programs/life3/SDL_stuf/customSDL.cpp:5: multiple definition of `renderera'
obj\Debug\main.o:C:/c++/programs/life3/Input/Input.h:28: first defined here
obj\Debug\SDL_stuf\customSDL.o: In function `ZSt4moveIRNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEEONSt16remove_referenceIT_E4typeEOS8_':
C:/c++/programs/life3/SDL_stuf/customSDL.cpp:5: multiple definition of `windowa'
obj\Debug\main.o:C:/c++/programs/life3/Input/Input.h:28: first defined here
obj\Debug\SDL_stuf\cView.o: In function `ZN4View4LineE5cordsS0_9SDL_Color':
C:/c++/programs/life3/SDL_stuf/cView.cpp:5: multiple definition of `renderera'
obj\Debug\main.o:C:/c++/programs/life3/Input/Input.h:28: first defined here
obj\Debug\SDL_stuf\cView.o: In function `ZN4View4LineE5cordsS0_9SDL_Color':
C:/c++/programs/life3/SDL_stuf/cView.cpp:5: multiple definition of `windowa'
obj\Debug\main.o:C:/c++/programs/life3/Input/Input.h:28: first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

вот два примера кода, первый, где переменная , якобы, переобъявляется, второй где она,  опять же якобы, обьявлена впервые

```
void Creature::make_move(int dir)
{// ТУТ ПЕРЕОБЬЯВЛЕНА
    switch( dir )
    {
    case RIGHT:
        x = x + spd;
    break;
    case LEFT:
        x = x - spd;
    break;
    case UP:
        y = y - spd;
    break;
    case DOWN:
        y = y + spd;
    break;
   }
}


cords Input::check_input()
{// И ЯКОБЫ НА ЭТОЙ СТРОЧКЕ ОБЬЯВЛЕНА ВПЕРВЫЕ
    if( SDL_PollEvent( &e ) != 0)
    {
        if( e.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN )
        {
            int mx,my;
            SDL_GetMouseState(&mx,&my);
            cords click = { mx,my };
            return click;
        }
    }
}
```

Хотя данная переменная обьявлена абсолютно в другом месте, как статичный указатель с функциями доставания

```
SDL_Renderer * renderera=nullptr;
SDL_Window * windowa=nullptr;
inline SDL_Renderer* get_rnd() { return renderera; }
inline SDL_Window* get_wnd() { return windowa; }
```

первые 20 строк Creature.cpp

```
#include "Creature.h"
void Creature::make_move(int dir)
{
    switch( dir )
    {
    case RIGHT:
        x = x + spd;
    break;
    case LEFT:
        x = x - spd;
    break;
    case UP:
        y = y - spd;
    break;
    case DOWN:
        y = y + spd;
    break;
    }
```

27,28,29 строка Input.h

```
cords Input::check_input()
{
    if( SDL_PollEvent( &e ) != 0)
```

Comment: Представленные куски не соответствуют сообщениям об ошибке, в которых указывается, что эти переменные определены в некотором заголовочном файле `Input.h`, что естественно приводит к ошибкам линковки.

Comment: @VTT сейчас добавлю код из инпута , там тоже самое

Comment: Покажите первые 10 строк файла `Creature.cpp` и 28 строку `Input.h`

Comment: @Anton добавил код. компилятор указывает на фигурные кавычки...

Comment: @VTT добавил код

Comment: Собственно я уже проголосовал за закрытие по причине отсутствия [mcve].

Comment: @VTT я извиняюсь за сумбурность, добавил код, компилятор указывает на фигурные кавычки, думая, что это обьявление, я 2 недели программирую и абсолютно не имею понятие, что это может значить...

Comment: Такое ощущение, что компилятор работает с другим кодом. Вы точно показываете эти файлы `C:/c++/programs/life3/Model/Creature.cpp`, `C:/c++/programs/life3/Input/Input.h`? Пути правильные? Нет у вас папки `C:/c++/programs/life2`?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov точно, я такой не создавал вовсе, была life1, но она уже удалена с диска..

Comment: @VTT просто какой тут может быть пример, если здесь явно что-то ненормальное происходит, какие могут быть примеры с несуществующими обьявлениями на строчках длиной в 1 символ - '{'

Comment: Пример должен быть минимальный и воспроизводимый ) Если читающие не могут воспроизвести у себя такую проблему, значит проблемы никакой нет.

Comment: @VTT мне не хватит опыта, чтобы из 500 строк вычленить,помимо тех, что есть, строки, которые как-то могут быть связанными с этой проблемой

Comment: @VTT поэтому я и пишу за помощью людям с опытом, которые, возможно, уже сталкивались с такой проблемой

Comment: @VTT я бы мог залить на гитхаб весь код, но мне кажется это либо мало чем поможет, либо не совсем правильно, укажите какие подробности вам нужны, чтобы воспроизвести проблему у себя

Comment: Там [по ссылке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) написано как это сделать...

Comment: @VTT я уже скинул все, что провоцирует проблему(на что жалуется компилятор), другой информации у меня нет

Comment: @VTT я конечно от отчаяния вечером переполошу весь код, но мало ли, вы уже сталкивались с этим, или кто-то другой

Comment: Ну так а ваше `SDL_Renderer * renderera=nullptr; SDL_Window * windowa=nullptr;` - это где располагается? В каком файле и в каком контексте? Почему вы в вопросе называете эти указатели "статичными"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из вашего описания можно сделать вывод, что объявления

```
SDL_Renderer * renderera=nullptr;
SDL_Window * windowa=nullptr;
inline SDL_Renderer* get_rnd() { return renderera; }
inline SDL_Window* get_wnd() { return windowa; }
```

у вас располагаются в некоем заголовочном файле, который включен в несколько файлов реализации. Это, разумеется, приводит к ошибкам множественного определения `renderera` и `windowa` (как и должно быть).

В GCC при компиляции с `-g` линкер в сообщениях об ошибках множественного определения выдает не только имена объектных файлов, в которых располагаются эти множественные определения, но и строчки исходных файлов, в которых эти определения были сделаны. В некоторых случаях линкер в такой ситуации указывает на бессмысленную строчку (см. напр. [комментарий](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7757234/how-do-i-understand-this-compiler-error-multiple-definition-of/7758903#comment9446876_7758903))

---

Ваша попытка "исправить ошибку" путем объявления `renderera` и `windowa` как `static` является, разумеется, бессмысленной профанацией. Эти переменные скорее всего задуманы как *глобальные*. Более того, такое "исправление" делает вашу программу некорректной. Это нарушение [ODR](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#12) (no diagnostic is required). [Inline-функциям с внешним связыванием](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#12.3) не разрешается ссылаться на [разные статические переменные в контексте разных единиц трансляции](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#12.13).

Простейший способ исправить ошибку в С++17 - объявить их как `inline`.

Answer (score -2):

Чтож, потыкаясь в код, решил обьявить SDL_Renderer * renderera и SDL_Window * windowa как статичные, это полностью решило проблему.
Спасибо, кто пытался помочь.

Comment: Не понял. Во-первых, у вас в вопросе ясно сказано, что эти указатели "статичные" (что бы это ни значило). Здесь же вы пишете, что только сейчас объявили их "статичными". Так были они уже "статичными" или нет? Во-вторых, если под "статичными" вы имеет в виду объявление как `static`, то это не "решит проблему", а лишь подавит ошибки линковки, создав при этом еще бОльшие проблемы.